# SQL Server 2008 service pack doesn't recognise database instance for upgrading

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, service-pack

SQL Server 2008 was installed into a brand new virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. There was a warning when running SQL Server setup to run Service Pack 1 after installation.

Once installed the service pack was run. It upgraded the setup files and then I believe the setup program quit (wasn't watching the screen at the time). Setup was then re-run and it suggested upgrading shared components. This ran successfully.

The problem is that the database instance (and other installed instances) are not being upgraded. The setup program is simply not detecting them. When connecting via SQL Server Management Studio, the build number of the database is still 1600.

How can the service pack be correctly installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have the correct edition of the service pack for the version of SQL Server you've already installed - there are 3. I suspect you're either trying to install the x86 SP on an x64 install or vice versa (I saw the same thing myself about a month ago when someone tried the x64 SP on an x86 install).

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is only 64bit, and unless you are lucky enough to have any itanium based server it is probably just the x64 version you want

Comment: D'oh! That was it. Thanks you saved me a lot of time!